When is a linear dynamical system without inputs and noise identifiable?
I have recently been reading up on the identifiability of linear dynamical systems, namely models following the form:
\begin{align*}
x_{t + 1} & = Ax_t+ Bu_t \\
y_t & = Cx_t
\end{align*}
where $\{y_t, u_t, x_t\}_{t \in \infty}$ are observed outputs, inputs, and unobserved latents respectively. My textbook states that the identifiability / uniqueness of a system is equivalent to the uniqueness of the Markov parameters, the latter of which are defined by $\{CB, CAB, \cdots , CA^{k}B, \cdots \}$.
However, the book does not provide conditions for identifiability in the case of $B = 0$, i.e. no inputs. Let us assume $A, C$ are invertible to avoid edge cases as well. In hopes of establishing some conditions, I have tried the following:
Suppose that there exist two models $(A, C), (A', C')$ such that their respective outputs $y_t = y_t'$ for all $t$. By definition, $y_t = CA^tx_0$, so $CA^tx_0 = C'(A')^tx_0$ for all $t$. In turn, the functions defined by
$$
f(w) = Ce^{wAx_0}
$$
and
$$
f'(w) = C'e^{wA'x_0}
$$
are equal for all $w$. I feel like there should be some way to establish relations between $(A, C), (A', C')$ from here, but have been unable to -- perhaps something like "A and A' must be similar matrices". Insight would be super appreciated.

Oh, thanks for the catch! Yes, $A, C$ should be invertible.
